# JPA Query not working for latest record fetch

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using this query to retrieve latest record based on runId, but this query is giving any result.

```
  @Query("select vr1 from VendorResult vr1 left join VendorResult vr2 on (vr1.applicationId = vr2.applicationId "
      + "and vr1.productType=vr2.productType and vr1.runId<vr2.runId) "
      + "where vr1.applicationId=?1 and vr1.overallStatus=?2 and vr2.applicationId is null")
  List<VendorResult> getVendorResults(String applicationId,String overallStatus);
```

Tried this also

```
  @Query(value = "select vs from VendorResult vs where vs.applicationId=?1 and vs.overallSatatus=?2 and vs.runId = (select max(v.runId) from VendorResult v where v.applicationId = vs.applicationId)",nativeQuery = true)
List<VendorResult> getVendorResults(String applicationId,String overallStatus);
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

a paginated select with a page long 1 and order by id desc will get you what you need

```
  @Query("select vr1 from VendorResult vr1 where vr1.applicationId=?1 and vr1.overallStatus=?2 order by vr1.runId DESC")
  List<VendorResult> getVendorResults(String applicationId,String overallStatus, Pageable pageable);
```

invoke with

```
repository.getVendorResults(applicationId, overallStatus, PagePageRequest.of(0, 1));
```